# Security & Malware Protection for Windows 2008 Server (with RDP)

Tags: windows, security, web-hosting, windows-server-2008-r2, malware

I am running an ASP.NET site on a windows 2008 server with RDP access to the server. Installing or enabling firewalls shuts off my RDP access and multiple other issues. My hosting provider is very barebones and DIY hence would need to figure out what kind of protection I can deploy.  Thought would ask the Stack-overflow Hivemind how they manage *remote* Windows boxes and what kind of protection mechanisms to deploy.

Answer (score 1):

First, firewall stop RDP only if you let it do. You can enable it again by opening the port. But also I suggest to change the default RDP port, and then just add it to the firewall to permit it.

[How to change the listening port for Remote Desktop](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306759)

http://theillustratednetwork.mvps.org/RemoteDesktop/RemoteDesktopSetupandTroubleshooting.html

http://www.nullamatix.com/howto-remote-desktop-at-work-evading-a-firewall/

Second, use a [tunneling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunneling_protocol) program to connect to your server and be real safe, because this way no one can snif your interaction with the server.

Plesk install by default a tunelling server, also [bitvise is very good](http://www.bitvise.com/tunnelier) and free for one connection only.

So to synopsis. Use tunnelling, change the default port on RDP and tunneling, open this posts on firewall, connect only using tunneling, also use SSL on your ftp connections, and finally use a port scanning program with your firewall.

To avoid problems with the firewall, make run a script on windows starts that turn off the firewall. This way if for any reason a program change the open ports on firewall and you fail to login, you make a remote reboot and on restart you are back again. This saves more for a lot of time.

Comment: +1 I will wait for a more responses.